# Fixed combinatorial logic

Tags: verilog

I have question.
my code is

```
module pulsing(OUT, an1, an2, or1);

input wire an1, an2, or1;
output wire OUT;

wire afa;

and andik(afa,an1,an2);
or orik(OUT,afa,or1);

endmodule
```

I got after synthesis one 3bit LUT result, but I really need 2 different 
LUTS .

How can I implement it without any sequential logic(just wires and 
LUTs)?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want two LUTs?

Comment: Thanks for respond. In my real case I need it, here I just want to know how to implement really what I write.

Comment: I have 10 inputs on real and it combines me it in to 2 Luts what is logically. But Oreder of inputs are mixed by implementator as it wants. I need some signals go throught one LUT and some can go through two. as one LUT has propagation about 700pS.

Answer (score 0):

You can define LUT2 as for AND gate:

```
LUT2 #(.INIT(4'h1)) U1(.O(O), 
                       .I0(I1),
                       .I1(I2));
```

And OR gate respectively as:

```
LUT2 #(.INIT(4'hE)) U1(.O(O), 
                       .I0(I1),
                       .I1(I2));
```

Notice the `.INIT` values. These are the truth table results of these Boolean functions.

```
I1  I0  O
0   0   B0
0   1   B1  
1   0   B2
1   1   B3
```

From this you can implement any 2 input Boolean function with a single LUT2. For example XOR would require .INIT(4'h6).

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I understood I can usee in this way MUX, DFF, and LATCH?

Comment: Yes you can create anything by using this. And there are other primitives like block ram and such. However you should not code in this way unless you know what you are doing. Because as you said synthesis tool uses 1 LUT3 to synthesize the circuit. Which is both faster, and more area efficient compared to using 2 LUTs. Also coding with LUTs automatically tie your code to specific FPGA. So try to code as close to hardware and let your synthesis tool to optimize but do this kind of optimizations only when necessary and you are specifically working for FPGA.